# Python3: Copy of text with some changes

Tags: python, parsing, text

I got this raw source text file:

```
Hello {Jane Peter},
I send a email to your address {Jane@a.com Peter@a.com}.
```

And I need to create 2 copies of this file for each person:
(items has the same index - Jane in the first {} is for Jane@a.com in second {})

```
Hello Jane,
I send a email to your address Jane@a.com.
```

And the second one:

```
Hello Peter,
I send a email to your address Peter@a.com
```

So the point is to select the item from {} and sub the whole {} with the select and create correct number of copies of the source text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code:

```
import re

s = '''Hello {Jane Peter},
I send a email to your address {Jane@a.com Peter@a.com}.'''

count = re.search('{(.*?)}', s).group(1).count(' ')
for i in range(count + 1):
    print(re.sub('{(.*?)}', lambda x: x.group(1).split()[i], s))
```

Output:

```
Hello Jane,
I send a email to your address Jane@a.com.
Hello Peter,
I send a email to your address Peter@a.com.
```

It will first use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) to find the first group to be replaced and then counts spaces in the match to figure out how many copies needs to be created. This of course works only if strings to be used in the template don't contain any spaces. If you already know how many copies are required this can be skipped.

Next code will generate the copies within the loop by using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search). `{(.*?)}` will match all tokens that need to be replaced and capture text between brackets. Then it will split captured text and use item at index currently being processed.

While the example works in this particular scenario I recommend checking real templating libraries for this kind of tasks. [`Jinja2`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/) is one popular option.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex to match the brackets, and then traverse the list and produce the string you need.

```
import re
matches = re.findall(r'\{([^}]+)\}', s)
# you should verify that matches indeed contains two elements
names = matches[0].split()
mails = matches[1].split()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Formatter.parse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#custom-string-formatting) to get the names/emails from the placeholders:

```
from string import Formatter

s = """Hello {Jane Peter},
I send a email to your address {Jane@a.com Peter@a.com}."""

names, emails = (p for _, p, _, s in Formatter().parse(s) if p)
s = s.replace(names,"").replace(emails,"")

for name, email in zip(names.split(), emails.split()):
    print(s.format(name, email))
```

Output:

```
Hello Jane,
I send a email to your address Jane@a.com.
Hello Peter,
I send a email to your address Peter@a.com.
```